# How to get Text Typed on CkEditor

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I´m trying to get typed text on ckeditor (textarea), but I have some trouble:

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editor').ckeditor();


    var editor = $('#editor').ckeditorGet(); 

    var data = $('#editor').val(); 
    window.alert(data);
    window.alert(CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData());

});
</script>

    <body>


<form method="post">
    <textarea  name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The results on two alerts are empty. What i´m doing wrong?

Comment: If you're doing this all on pageload, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: @jboneca I don´t understand at all what will be the solution. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are calling the alerts when the **page loads**. At that time, there is nothing yet on the textarea.

Bind the event to something that will happen **after** the textbox has something to show, for example, when you click the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editor').ckeditor();
    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
        window.alert($('#editor').val());
    });
});
```

Also, you may want to bind the click event to the `document` instead, so it will happen even if you add new submits programatically. For that to happen, bind the event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function() {
    window.alert($('#editor').val());
});
```

Comment: could you help me a little? How can I update now my textarea with typed text?

Comment: The same way you got its value. By calling $('#editor').val('New text!')